# Как организовать на golang копирование файлов с одного клиента на другой по сети?

Tags: http, golang, websocket, ftp, fileupload

Есть два приложения на golang. Одно серверное,другое клиентское.
Они общаются по http и http->websocket *(либо предложите другой протокол)*
Нужно скопировать папку с находящимися в ней файлами и папками по сети в другое приложение.
Есть ли нормальный алгоритм, как это лучше сделать?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Можно паковать файлы/папки в .tar.gz и сразу отправлять в соединение (tcp) вместо файла, а на другом конце вычитывать архив и тут же его распаковывать на лету.

Если там веб-сервер уже реализован - можно тот же tar.gz отправить в виде POST-запроса, например как браузер делает.

Обход дерева файлов/папок: https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Walk

Запаковка в tar: https://golang.org/pkg/archive/tar/

Сжатие: https://golang.org/pkg/compress/gzip/

Comment: Лить можно и через горутины без архивации с синхроном через sync. А так поддерживаю, самый логично простой способ.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, рассмотреть MQ-технологию. Возможно [rabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), может быть ZeroMQ [статья с хабра](https://habrahabr.ru/post/198578/).

если кратко, то результатом вы получаете отдельный сервер управления сообщениями между теми кто на них подписан. Что то типа межпроцессорного взаимодействия.Плюс различные гарантии доставки и умные очереди.

если выбирите рэбит то там очень простой хелоу-ворлд, и поддерживаются почти все популярные языки. И одного вечера будет достаточно что бы написать и уже попробовать в действии.

Comment: Как обмен сообщениями вообще связан с передачей файлов?

Comment: файл может быть сообщением

Comment: Это очень ограниченный кейс с кучей доп ограничений, например на место - rabbitMQ должен иметь место чтобы вместить файл целиком. Его нужно администрировать, его нельзя засунуть внутрь приложения. Это может подойти если файлы маленькие и rabbitMQ уже и так используется - тогда да, можно и через него сообщения слать просто потому что он уже есть и доп. сложности не несет. В общем случае я думаю это плохое решение.

Comment: поэтому как вариант.

Comment: Ну это очень частный вариант. Примерно как на вопрос: "Как мне добраться до библиотеки?" вариант: "Вы садитесь в свой автомобиль с персональным водителем и говорите - вези меня в библиотеку". Вполне вариант и вполне имеет право на жизнь, только в очень ограниченном числе случаев.

Comment: всегда полезно знать альтернативу для того что бы выбрать свой путь.

Comment: зачем в решение простейшей задачи пихать всякий ненужный мусор. При чем тут кролик. Задача передача кучи файлов по C/S over http(s). Оптимальный и самый простой путь - указан ответом выше `rekby`.Это - выделение нужных файлов(директорий) в представленной форме, отправка на сервер, обработка и выполнения нужного алгоритма (архивация, передача, уведомление о результате). Все.

Answer (score 0):

Похожую задачу я реализовал с помощью SFTP сервера на машине откуда нужно было отдавать файлы и клиента на go там куда нужно копировать, используя SSH авторизацию, возможно кому то будет полезно

[GoLang: автоматизировать копирование файлов с одного сервера на другой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/947478/golang-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9/965474#965474)