# GoLang: автоматизировать копирование файлов с одного сервера на другой

Tags: golang, sftp

Необходимо организовать копирование файлов по сети с одного сервера на другой

При этом нужно **копировать файлы в разные папки** на целевой машине в зависимости от формата имени файла.

**C:/Program Files/aProgram/files/FILENAME__15122018.ext1 
===> /home/work/sourcedir1

C:/Program Files/aProgram/files/15122018_FILENAME.ext2
===> /home/work/sourcedir2**

В C:/Program Files/aProgram/files/ лежит набор файлов и регулярно обновляется
и это Windows машина (**PC1**)
Есть PC2  куда нужно копировать файлы и это Unix машина (**PC2**)

При этом копирование должно происходить по защищенному каналу регулярно (раз в день)

Из того что я смог придумать неимея опыта такого рода задач:

Поднять самописный на go СФТП сервер на PC1 на нужной папке, организовать SSH-keys авторизацию.
На PC2 сфтп клиентом читать папку и различая по фармату файлов копировать по нужным папкам..

Может кто имел опыт подобного и может подсказать

Comment: Лучше всего для этого подходит rsync по ssh, который раз в день будет запускаться через cron.

Comment: [Инструкция](https://www.dmosk.ru/instruktions.php?object=rsync-server).

Comment: Есл все работает - нормальный вариант.

Comment: @OlegUtkin спасибо, было бы неплохо отделаться rsync но 1) можно ли rsyncom реализовать копирование по маске? то есть файлы одного вида в один каталог а другого в другой? 2) можно ли синхронизировать файлы с виндовс машины на линукс ? (видел по ссылке про cwRsync нонеуверен сможет он отдавать файлы еа нативный линуксовый rsync?)

Comment: 1) Да, в статье есть пример с --include, --exclude; 2) cwRsync совместим с линуксовым rsync

Comment: @OlegUtkin Спасибо! Разобрался с копированием по маске и с настройкой сервера, все работает. Но всплыла дополнительная специфика -

Comment: - при наличии нескольких файлов одного вида нужно копировать только один (последний по дате). Попытаюсь обойти это требование какой-гибудь надстройкой (bash wrapper?) - или урергулировать со стороны тз и оставить копирование всех файлов, если нет - вернусь к варианту  с Go-Sftp.  В любом случае распишу вариант с Rsync в ответе на вопрос когда закончу задачу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Спасибо всем за помощь**, к сожалению не удалось отделаться средствами rsync хотя для очень широкого спектра задач rsync наверное лучший выбор. Команды rsync к которым я пришел позволяли мне копировать файлы по нужным каталогам

```
rsync.exe -a -m --include='*.ext1' --exclude='*' backup@127.0.0.1::local_copying /cygdrive/d/rsync_in/ext1files
```

**НО** как оказалось нужно было реализовать дополнительную логику где rsync недостаточно -архивирование скопированных файлов и др. Так же оставить пространство для расширения наработок по схожим задачам копирования. **В итоге** написал програмку на golang с конфигурационным файлом где указывал что и куда копировать. Используя следующие пакеты:

```
"github.com/micro/go-config"
"github.com/pkg/sftp"
"golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
```

Comment: где можно глянуть реализацию??

Comment: @Azamat к сожалению кода нет в открытом доступе, делал для предприятия.